# CSS flex item spacing & alignment - space without padding/margin & -webkit-inline-box vs inline-flex for baseline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Have couple of questions related to Flex container items space and aligning to baseline.

1. How to have space between elements within flex container items without using padding or margin? Is there any other way with flex props? For e.g.: Between "Main text content here" and "ClickMeHere", as well as between "ClickMeHere" and icon next to it in the below screenshot from codepen output.

[image]

2. Seems using display:-webkit-inline-box is better aligned to the baseline than display:inline-flex. Observed this in chrome/edge for 11X11 icon size (but not seeing any difference in codepen for 14X14 size though). So is it good to use -webkit-inline-box instead of inline-flex?

```css
.mybar {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #323130;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}
.mybar.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.mybar :hidden {
  display: none;
}
.mybar.warning {
  background-color: red;
}
.mybar .mybar-content {
  margin: 7px 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.mybar .icon {
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.mybar .close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mybar .hyperlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.mybar .my2-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.mybar .mycontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
.mybar .inlineflexcontent {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.mybar .svg-i-16x16-alert {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/B67xSz8Y/73028-warning-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.mybar .svg-i-16x16-close {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/MpPMjFb1/iconfinder-Delete-132746.png");
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.mybar .svg-i-14x14-link {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/mD5NTrh1/11x11-icon.png'");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybar" >
    <div class="mybar-content">
        <div class="svg-i-16x16-alert icon" [ngClass]="iconClass"></div>
        <div class="mycontainer">
            <div class="inlineflexcontent">
                <div>Main text content here</div>
                <div class="hyperlink">
                    <span>ClickMeHere</span>
                    <span class="svg-i-14x14-link my2-icon"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>Another optional text here </div>            
            <div>
                <div class="svg-i-16x16-close close-button" tabindex="0">                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CodePen: https://codepen.io/madhu_s05/pen/rNOqBXG

Comment: Inline box is an older version of the flexbox syntax and should not be used.

Comment: `Main text content here` `ClickMeHere` and the `icon` are not within the same flex container therefore having space between them would be a bit tricky, as for your second question it's a unclear

Answer (score 0):

Space between relies on the flex element having a defined width - if you use the following, you will see that the space-between is working correctly:

```css
.inlineflexcontent {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Obviously this isn't what you want to achieve. In this instance, I would change the above to use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) instead of Flex, which will allow you to define space between elements without using padding or margins:

```css
.inlineflexcontent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; // two equal columns
    grid-gap: 1rem; // spacing between columns
  }
```

Comment: In case the part about "defined width" causes confusion - I have attempted to demonstrate simply in this Codepen why space-between will not work in this case: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/WinningWebDesign/pen/VwvELKQ)

Comment: Thanks @DannyXCII for your clarifications with a codepen and on your suggestion to go for Grid instead of Flex.
Do you have any thoughts on the 2nd question related to using -webkit-inline-box that aligns better than inline-flex even though this looks like not recommended to use. I see this shows up in developer tools much often.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do few changes as below:

```css
    .mycontainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .inlineflexcontent {
        display: inline-flex;
        width: 30%;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Please, give a `width` in percentage to `.inlineflexcontent`. Since  `.inlineflexcontent` itself is a flex item of `.container`, it squeezes itself to the minimum possible width just enough to display its content. So, without giving it a width in percentage, we cannot see any of the `justify-content` property's values to work on it. Once you have given the width, then go ahead to apply `justify-content: space-between;` on `.inlineflexcontent`.